# Sumar valores, agrupando columnas iguales en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

He buscando información pero no logro encontrarla

Tengo la siguienta tabla en MySql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito realizar una consulta de manera que, según vaya cambiando el nro_rendicion, me indique el monto total y otros datos importantes, por ejemplo:

nro_rendicion = 'ci20', fecha_rendición = '2023-05-23', total monto = 21600

nro_rendicion = 'pg20', fecha_rendición = '2023-05-24', total monto = 5500

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es literalmente lo que dices en el título, un `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    nro_rendicion,
    fecha_rendicion,
    SUM(monto) as `total monto`
FROM tabla
GROUP BY 
    nro_rendicion,
    fecha_rendicion
```

Comment: Si!, correcto, así era. Necesito un curso sobre GROUP BY, siempre me ha costado ese tema. Gracias.